# How to return data from first observable despite error inner?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have two streams one by one:

```
  .pipe(
                   
                    map(() => new SemanticObject(this.objectLayer, this.map)),
                    concatMap((semanticObject: SemanticObject) =>
                        from(semanticObject.saveObject(semanticObject.getObject())).pipe(
                            concatMap(() => semanticObject.changeObjectStateUnom()),
                            map((data) => data;
                        ),
                    ),
                )
```

I try to return data from first stream here `map((data) => data;`. despite if concatMap is failed. How to do that?

I have tried this:

```
.pipe(
                    tap(() => this.loading$.next(false)),
                    filter(Boolean),
                    map(() => new SemanticObject(this.objectLayer, this.map)),
                    concatMap((semanticObject: SemanticObject) =>
                        from(semanticObject.saveObject(semanticObject.getObject())).pipe(


                            concatMap((updatedObject: ObjectLayer) => semanticObject.changeObjectStateUnom().pipe(
                                catchError((updatedObject) => updatedObject),
                                mapTo(updatedObject)
                            )),
                        ),
                    ),
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're so close! `CatchError` is a higher-order operator (like concatMap, but for errors), so you need to return an observable.

For example:

```ts
pipe(
  tap(() => this.loading$.next(false)),
  filter(Boolean),
  map(() => new SemanticObject(this.objectLayer, this.map)),
  concatMap((semanticObject: SemanticObject) =>
    from(semanticObject.saveObject(semanticObject.getObject()))
  ),
  concatMap((updatedObject: ObjectLayer) => 
    semanticObject.changeObjectStateUnom().pipe(

      catchError(error => of("Error Token")),
      map(changedState => 
        changedState === "Error Token" ? 
        updatedObject : changedState
      )

    )
  )
);
```

Of course, using a string as an error token isn't idiomatic, but you can choose whatever works best for you.

Comment: @Jessy Looking at this again, it seems like you have an unnecessary level of nesting. More of a stylistic thing, but I've updated my answer to remove it if you're interested.